# How to load and store a folder of Images

Tags: c#, image, list, directory

I have a team program underway and my part is to add the ability to load either a single image or  (more likely) a folder of images and them save them so that other aspects the program will be able to access them.

Here are my actual questions:

1. I need an example on how to display a `Open File` or `Open Folder` dialog.
2. An example of the best way to store all of the images in the folder.

*Note:* I will need to eventually display these images but it will be after another part of the program reorders them based on color.

Comment: Desktop application or web application?  ASP.NET or MVC?

Comment: [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/)

Comment: As of yet nothing I've have lots of issues even getting C# to work and open my project. But I want to get a good idea of whats should be going on before I start anyway.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Somthing like this maybe:

```
     Dictionary<string, Bitmap> images = new Dictionary<string, Bitmap>();

        string[] extensions = new string[]{".BMP",".JPG",".GIF",".PNG"};
        var fd = new System.Windows.Forms.FolderBrowserDialog();
        if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
        {
            foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(fd.SelectedPath).Where(f => extensions.Contains(Path.GetExtension(f).ToUpper())))
            {
                images.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file), new Bitmap(file));
            }
        }
```

Or Open File:

```
     var fd = new System.Windows.Forms.OpenFileDialog();
     fd.Filter = "Image Files(*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG)|*.BMP;*.JPG;*.GIF;*.PNG";
     if (fd.ShowDialog() == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
     {
         images.Add(Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(fd.FileName,new Bitmap(fd.FileName));
     }
```

Comment: I haven't tested it yet but looks good, however the above code only accepts Folder right? I've been looking around and it seem a Open file or Folder dialog is not an easy thing to accomplish so maybe a Folder only dialog is good enough.

Comment: Thank you I'm going to work with this for awhile, if i have any issues ill post back here.

Comment: Ok so question in the code~

    foreach (var file in Directory.GetFiles(fd.SelectedPath,"*.png"))

~ what would be the correct way to accept all Image file types?

Comment: There is no real nice way to do this, but I have updated the answer with a way that works fine for me :)

Comment: Thank you, may not be the cleanest of code, but it is alot more understandable then other examples I've have seen.